# Stumped by d3 error I'm receiving - Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNL21.923076923…"

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to convert a d3 sparkline example on codepen (https://codepen.io/jakelear-1472051722/pen/bRbqBB) so that it pulls data in from a csv file. Here is my code:

```
d3.csv("sparkline.csv", function (error, data) {

    if (error) throw error;

    // format the data
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        currentValue = +d.currentValue;

    });

    var graph = d3.select('.sparkline').append("svg").attr("width", "100%").attr("height", "100%");

    var height = parseInt(graph.style("height"));
    var width = parseInt(graph.style("width"));  

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, data.length])
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
        .range([height, 0]);

    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d,i) {
            return x(i);
        })

        .y(function(d) {
            return y(currentValue);
        });

    graph.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);

});
```

I'm receiving the following error: **d3.v4.js:1382 Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNL21.923076923…"** and have been struggling trying to figure this out.

The contents of my CSV file:

```
currentValue
2.0
2.3
1.9
1.7
1.7
2.2
2.3
2.2
2.0
2.1
1.9
2.0
1.6
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm sure it's something small I'm just not seeing.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` is not a simple, flat array, but an array of objects.

Therefore, it should be:

```
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.currentValue})])
    .range([height, 0]);
```

Besides that, remember to correctly provide a reference to the object. In the forEach loop:

```
data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.currentValue = +d.currentValue;

});
```

And in the line generator:

```
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d,i) {
        return x(i);
    })

    .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.currentValue);
    });
```